# Is it better to define a "year" column to be of type Integer or String?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I do realize that it is better for a column to be an Integer if one has to perform mathematical calculations on it.

I probably have to perform mathematical calculations on the "year" column but minimally. So would it be better to store it as a String or Integer?

Thanks.

Comment: it is an integer. why would you want to not-save it as one? when in doubt: save it as the type it actually is.

Comment: @Nanne, it is actually a [year](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/year.html) though isn't it.

Comment: @Nanne but one does not really think of years as Integers, it's kind of like thinking of phone numbers. I think of phone numbers as strings. Integers as I understand would be things like "price" or "amount" etc.. or am I wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Always store you data in the most restrictive type you can get away with.

Comment: It does not really matter how you see them, it matters what they are ;)

Comment: (the difference with phonenumbers btw is that the year 001 is the same as year 1. But phonenumbers CAN have leading zeros. So yes, phonenumbers are string. and years aren't).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Save it as an integer.

While there may be some application where you are reading and serving this data so frequently that the int->string conversion is a problem... that is going to be an edge case.

On the other side

- Integers provide smaller options than strings in data storage (such as TINYINT)
- You avoid conversions due to math
- It's going to confuse/annoy/frustrate all the developers that come after you when they query a data type that is naturally a number and get a string.

Answer (score 3):

If you are not expecting your `YEAR` variable to ever contain non-digit values then yes you should store it as a number.

I would not store it as `INT` since I doubt year will reach the limit that `INT` has to offer. I would save it as `SMALLINT` or even `TINYINT` either should be `unsigned`.

`SMALLINT UNSIGNED` gives you max value of `65535`, unless you are storing years that exceed the year `65535` this should suffice.

Answer (score 1):

You could go crazy and save it as a [`YEAR`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/year.html)!

This limits you to 1901-2155

You can do things like

```
WHERE year < CURDATE()
```

without worries then.

Comment: The `YEAR` datatype is custom made for representing a "year" value. One issue is how the `YEAR` datatype is handled/represented/converted in the client library (e.g. Perl DBI, MySQL JDBC connector, et al.) And to clarify, MySQL does _not_ store DATETIME as strings internally. A DATETIME occupies 8 bytes of storage, though this may have been changed in a more recent release (>5.5).

Comment: @spencer7593 I imagine it gets output as a string upon querying, much as datetime does and has been around for as far back as the docs; I'm fairly sure a client library will handle it. You are totally correct about the DATETIME storage however.. I have updated the answer.

Comment: CHAR(4) allows values like `19 3`. IMHO, this is not an improvement over one of the integer data types.